# How to convert many Spark dataframe column types at once?

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have 1000s of columns in my Spark dataframe. I have a function below to convert the column type one by one. But I want to be able to convert all column types to type double at once. Below code is useful to do for one column at a time.

```
def convertcolumn(df, name, new_type):
    df_1 = df.withColumnRenamed(name, "swap")
    return df_1.withColumn(name, df_1["swap"].cast(new_type)).drop("swap")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can for example fold over the columns:

```
from functools import reduce

mapping = [("x", "double"), ("y", "integer")]
df = sc.parallelize([("1.0", "1", "foo")]).toDF(["x", "y", "z"])
reduce(lambda df, kv: convertcolumn(*(df, ) + kv), mapping, df)
```

or simply build a list of expressions and `select`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

mapping_dict = dict(mapping)

exprs = [col(c).cast(mapping[c]) if c in mapping_dict else c for c in df.columns]
df.select(*exprs)
```

Comment: @ zero323 Thanks for the reply. I am already using spark 1.6.3(pyspark) and still facing the problem. My code took more than 3 hours still it was not finished. Please give some suggestions. Thanks

Comment: Also in pyspark ml.pipeline in 1.6 does not have setCheckpointInterval parameter.